# Menu Page State

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

So, I have a jquery menu using UL and LI's. I wanted a page state so as to display to the user which page he's in by keeping a hover state on the menu item.

I've created a javascript file to function and read data when the user clicks a link. This function sets a cookie with the text data retrieved from the li

```
function setCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expireDate = new Date()
    //set "expstring" to either future or past date, to set or delete cookie, respectively
    var expstring=(typeof days!="undefined")? expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate()+parseInt(days)) : expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate()-5)
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+"; expires="+expireDate.toGMTString()+"; path=/";
    }

        function enact(what){                
             var value = $(what).text()                 
             setCookie(&quot;selected&quot;, value, 60)
        }

        function enactHome(){
             setCookie(&quot;selected&quot;, "Home", 60)
        }

        function enactLog(){
             setCookie(&quot;selected&quot;, "Log", 60)
        }</pre>
```

Then I have the following (read the cookie and if it's the same as the text, set the style):

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li onclick="enact(this);" <?php if($_COOKIE["selected"] == "Home"){ echo "class='navselected'"; }?> ><a href="index1.php">Home</a></li>

<li onclick="enact(this);" <?php if($_COOKIE["selected"] == "Student"){ echo "class='navselected'"; }?>><a href="#">Student</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li onclick="enact(this);"><a href="add_student.php">Add Student</a></li>
                            <li onclick="enact(this);"><a href="edit_student.php">Edit/Delete Student</a></li>                              
                        </ul>
                    </li>

<li onclick="enact(this);" <?php if($_COOKIE["selected"] == "User Log"){ echo "class='navselected'"; }?>><a href="log.php">User Log</a></li>    
</ul>
```

Now the problem is that the Student Link works upon loading the page and sets the menu state with a background in css as it should. The others do set the css, but the page has to be refreshed again. So if I click Home, the page loads with the student selected. When the page is refrehed, it loads the home selected.

I have tried to use the enactHome() and encatLog() on the Home and Log, but with no success. What am I doing wrong? Please help ;/

Thanks,
Francesco

Answer (score 0):

You could give unique `id`s to your menu items and body of each page and do it with css.
I don't understand why use a cookie and go through all that trouble. I might be missing something.

**html**

```
<body id="page-about">
.
.
.
<ul>
    <li><a id="menu-about"></a></li>
</ul>
```

**css**

```
#page-about #menu-about { background: red; }
```

Comment: mainly because that page is used once as the header of each page. So in terms, i have this HEADER page which contains the logo, menu and top stuff, CONTENT page which contains the main content, and FOOTER page which contains the footer area.